# What is the "as syntax" pointed out by tslint?

Tags: typescript, tslint

I upgraded tslint and now it complains about:

```
ERROR: src/Metronome/JobFetcher.ts[13, 32]: Type assertion using the '<>' syntax is forbidden. Use the 'as' syntax instead.
```

The offending code looks like:

```
const jobs = <JobConfig[]> <any> await rp(fetchJobsOptions);
```

What is the as syntax though and why should I use it?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Refactor your code like this:

```
const jobs = await rp(fetchJobsOptions) as JobConfig[];
```

As pointed out in the [TypeScript Deep Dive book by Basarat Ali Syed](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/type-assertion#as-foo-vs.-less-than-foo-greater-than), it says about type casting:

> ## as foo vs. `<foo>`
>
> Originally the syntax that was added was `<foo>`. This is demonstrated
> below:
>
> ```
> var foo: any;
> var bar = <string> foo; // bar is now of type "string"
> ```
>
> However there is an ambiguity in the language grammar when using
>
> ```
> <foo> style assertions in JSX:
> var foo = <string>bar;
> </string>
> ```
>
> Therefore it is now recommended that you just use as foo for
> consistency.
>
> ## Type Assertion vs. Casting
>
> The reason why it's not called "type casting" is that casting
> generally implies some sort of runtime support. However type
> assertions are purely a compile time construct and a way for you to
> provide hints to the compiler on how you want your code to be
> analyzed.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to suppress the error, you can as well go to `tslint.json` and include

```
...
"rules": {
    "no-angle-bracket-type-assertion": false,
    ...
}
...
```

provided you don't mind consistence as said.