# How to know which rule violation caused the error in tslint?

Tags: typescript, tslint

Related to [my question about the as-syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44202311/what-is-the-as-syntax-pointed-out-by-tslint), I wanted to look up the [tslint rules](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/) in order to figure out what went wrong. Alas, I only see error messages of my `tslint` run like this:

```
ERROR: src/Metronome/JobFetcher.ts[13, 32]: Type assertion using the '<>' syntax is forbidden. Use the 'as' syntax instead.
ERROR: src/Metronome/JobConfig.ts[20, 1]: Consecutive blank lines are forbidden
ERROR: src/Metronome/JobFetcher.ts[7, 23]: ' should be "
```

What is missing here is the rule that caused that error. For example, I *know* that the line `' should be "` relates to the rule `quotemark` in my `tsconfig.json`:

```
"quotemark": [
    true,
    "double",
    "avoid-escape"
],
```

Yet I do not know that for the other rules and since I rely upon `tslint:recommended` for the bulk of my configuration, it becomes hard for me to look them up once an error occurs I have not seen before, as happened with as-syntax, which I only solved by googling for the as syntax, not via the reference documentation of tslint.

How to know which rules of my tslint config caused the error message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`verbose` output formatter prints rule name:

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/tslint --format verbose --config tslint.js src/render/renderer.ts
ERROR: (no-unused-expression) src/render/renderer.ts[23, 5]: unused expression, expected an assignment or function call
ERROR: (semicolon) src/render/renderer.ts[104, 11]: Missing semicolon
ERROR: (semicolon) src/render/renderer.ts[110, 48]: Missing semicolon
```