# What is the difference between angle brackets and "as'' in Typescript 2?

Tags: typescript

**What is the difference between using `as` or `<>` in the code below?**

Option A - use 'as' for the return value

```
convertResultToParams(columnView:IColumnViewResult):IColumnViewParams {
    const params = {};

    Object.keys(this.getDefaultParams())
        .map(key => params[key] = columnView[key]);

    return params as IColumnViewParams;
}
```

Option B - use 'brackets' for the return value

```
convertResultToParams(columnView:IColumnViewResult):IColumnViewParams {
    const params = {};

    Object.keys(this.getDefaultParams())
        .map(key => params[key] = columnView[key]);

    return <IColumnViewParams>params;
}
```

**And why can't I just declare the type in the variable declaration?**

[image]

Comment: It is saying you are trying to assign an reference of type `{}` which is a plain object to a reference that requires a type `IColumnViewParams` which is illegal, it has nothing to do with `<>` or `as` which is used for "type casting"

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44202311/what-is-the-as-syntax-pointed-out-by-tslint

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your interface probably has members that are required, so initializing to `{}` is not valid. You can cast `{}` to the interface type if you are initializing it then, and will add the fields shortly.

```
const params = {} as IColumnViewParams
```

Initially Typescript used `<>` for casting, but with the addition of jsx support this became a problem so the `as` casting operator was added. There is not difference in the casting, just the context where you can use them. `as` can be used anywhere, `<>` cannot be used in tsx