# Writing simple test in Typescript gives type assertion error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-dom

Using typescript to define a test outputs `Type assertion using the '<>' syntax is forbidden. Use the 'as' syntax instead.` error.

**./app.test.ts**

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, div); // here the error is produced
});
```

How should the component be defined in Typescript?

[Example code from CRA Facebook page](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/running-tests#testing-components)

---

*edit: Accepted answer by @rzelek pointed in the right direction.*

As defined in the [JSX handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html#basic-usage) the compiler options define the way your JSX is interpreted. In my case used `"jsx": "react"` so that means the method **React.createElement()** needs to be used in order to create a component (see table in JSX handbook):

final result: **./app.test.ts**

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const app = React.createElement(App);
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(app, div);
});
```

Comment: Is this in a tsx file ?

Comment: Yes, also tried it as ts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript files that contain `JSX` should have `*.tsx` extension instead of `.ts`.

You can see similar issue here: https://github.com/palantir/tslint-react/issues/141

Additionally, your `tsconfig.json` should have appropriate config. For my CRA apps, this is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "jsx": "preserve",
    ...
  }
}
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html

The error you can see most probably comes from tslint, not Typescript itself. You can see a rule here: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-angle-bracket-type-assertion/. Basic tslint config for CRA should be something similar to this:

```
{
  "extends": ["tslint:latest", "tslint-react"],
  "rules": {
    // override tslint-react rules here
    "jsx-wrap-multiline": false
  }
}
```

As a good starting point, you can try adding `"no-angle-bracket-type-assertion": false` to `tslint.json` rules and see if error disappears.

PS. tslint usually points you to source of the error, for example:
`ERROR: app/components/Root/index.ts[6, 7]: Type assertion using the '<>' syntax is forbidden. Use the 'as' syntax instead.`

Comment: Yes, the app has it: `App.tsx`. Also tried `app.test.tsx` and `app.test.ts`

Comment: Tried  `"jsx": "preserve",` and  `"jsx": "react",`

Answer (score 0):

How's your `<App>` component defined?

Let's assume these are the component props and state interfaces (I usually define them in the beginning of a file for each component):

```
interface Props {
   //... some props
}
interface State {
   //... some state
}
```

A class component can be defined like this

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component<Props, State> { ... }
```

A function component can be defined like this

```
const MyComponent: React.FC<Props> = ...
```

You might want to check [react-redux-typescript-guide](https://github.com/piotrwitek/react-redux-typescript-guide)

Also, [this question might be related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44202311/what-is-the-as-syntax-pointed-out-by-tslint)

Comment: That is correct, defined it as: `class App extends React.Component<IAppProps, IAppState>`

Comment: Do you use type assertion in your component? see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44202311/what-is-the-as-syntax-pointed-out-by-tslint